# Non-www to www redirect not working in Firefox; Works in Chrome with nginx server

Tags: https, security-certificate, nginx, lets-encrypt

I've configured my website to have `https` with `www` scheme. I opted to redirect all the traffic from non-www to www, at the time of setting up LetsEncrypt SSL certificate and it works absolutely fine on Chrome (both desktop and mobile).

However, one of my site's member informed me that if they enter the non-www url in Firefox or Safari, I get Not-Secure server error. I tested and found out that Firefox and Safari refuse to redirect the site from non-www to proper `https`with `www` url like Chrome does.

How do I fix this issue? Here's my nginx configuration

```
server {

    root /var/www/ce/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 2M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



    server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're not seeing a cached response in Chrome (clear your browser cache and try Chrome on another machine). Do you have any other `server {}` blocks? You seem to be missing a closing `}` for the first `server` block? (Maybe Nginx auto-closes the `server` block when it reaches another `server` block?).